# Running bittorrent unto flash memory

Tags: bittorrent

My tablet has internal, irreplaceable, flash storage.

How advisable or inadvisable is it to run a torrent client on my tablet?

Comment: Personally, I don't see the point of getting flash storage if I'll never use it 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of reasons not to, firstly, you're unlikely to have a good stable connection with wireless, have insufficient space for decently large torrents, and might cause un-necessary wear and tear on your system - while flash has gotten more reliable in terms of write cycles before failure, take into account that if your storage is gone, its *gone* - especially if its soldered on flash chips.

Even a second or third hand junker PC might be a better option, with a large enough USB hard drive to save finished files to.

Comment: I found your [answer here](http://superuser.com/a/161147/57438) as well. I agree; Its write speed is slowing the download speed anyway. Using a USB drive (USB OTG) is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch for ctorrent that combat some issues with bittorrent and flash memory. First off it uses a new file format to store the torrent and second it minimize the random write access to the file. Instead of a simple sparse file it uses a red-black tree and max out i/o. Unfortunatley it's an old version of ctorrent that only support HTTP trackers in the torrent file. Any other tracker in the torrent file will make the torrent unusuable hence you must delete it with a torrent editor. I've some good experience with this patch and my Nokia N900. The patch is here: https://wiki.cc.gatech.edu/epl/index.php/FlashLite. I've posted also a  feature request here: http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/ticket/2438. It would be nice to have this patch in other torrent libraries.