# Can I perserve my SSD lifespan if I use utorrent Portable on a separate disk?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, ssd, utorrent

I am using a laptop with SSD ( Windows 10), and I have an external normal hard disk, with [utorrent portable software](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/utorrent_portable) on it.  When I want to download movies, I would plug my external hard disk on the laptop, and start my utorrent portable.exe to do it.

So all of my torrent files, the torrent read/write and even the movies are located on my external hard disk, outside of my main SSD.

Given that [the lifetime of a SSD is probably in total number of writes per cell](https://superuser.com/a/161150/522),

> That said, check out the lifetime of the SSD. It is probably in total
>   number of writes per cell. As such, more writes means sooner death. If
>   using it for bittorrent means you would use it more, yes, it will die
>   sooner.

can I preserve my SSD lifespan this way, since the SSD should be completely unutilized when I am torrenting on a completely separately hard drive?

Comment: similar questions has been asked *many* times in this forum, just search. modern SSDs will outlast your use of them.

Comment: @Keltari, are you sure? The accepted answer that I link to says that "As such, more writes means sooner death. If using it for bittorrent means you would use it more, yes, it will die sooner." This contradicts with what you assert in the comment

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/990710/how-damaged-is-my-ssd-disc/990715#990715 is my 'go to' answer on the old wife's tale of SSD death by use. THat said, I use an external drive for my torrents simply cause linux livecds are large, and I'd much rather have em on a scratch disk than a system disk

Comment: Probbaly because similar questions have already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are your SSD will die due to other reasons - modern SSDs are pretty hard to wear out. Quoting myself is a *pain* and [you want to read my other answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/990710/how-damaged-is-my-ssd-disc/990715#990715).

Chances are your drive will die of something else *before* they wear out.

That said, I *personally* do my torrenting to a old school, spinning rust hard drive. Torrent downloads don't need high IOPS, low latency and generally aren't sensitive to write speeds. Its a waste of the SSD's strengths. Having *lots* of storage is handy, and having a second hard drive is nice since your main hard drive won't get filled up with random stuff. There's *no* advantage whatsoever for running your torrents on a SSD

Answer (score 0):

It depends if it's an old or recent drive and if it's a good quality model. You can read [this article](http://techreport.com/review/27436/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-two-freaking-petabytes) about an endurance test someone did on different SSD drives. This guy managed to write 2,097,152 GB (2PB) of data on an SSD and it was still working after all this! The problem about SSD drives it's the amount of space they have. If you keep your movies in your SSD, you will run out of space very quickly...